# Jquery datetime picker not display in input field added with Jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.1 and trying to dynamically add input fields to form. This works OK but Datetimepicker not show. Here is my code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Event', array('novalidate' => true)); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Admin Add Event'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
?>
</fieldset>

<h2>Terms</h2>
<table id="mytable">
<tr><th></th><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>End Register</th><th>Location</th></tr>
<tr id="term0" style="display:none;">
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('&nbsp;-&nbsp;',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to remove this term')); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.from',array('label'=>'', 'type' => 'text')); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.to',array('label'=>'', 'type' => 'text')); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.register_end',array('label'=>'', 'type' => 'text')); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unused.location_id',array('label'=>'')); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr id="trAdd"><td> <?php echo $this->Form->button('+',array('type'=>'button','title'=>'Click Here to add another term','onclick'=>'addTerm()')); ?> </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var lastRow=0;

function addTerm() {
    lastRow++;
    $("#mytable tbody>tr:#term0").clone(true).attr('id','term'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr:#trAdd");
    $("#term"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removeTerm('+lastRow+')');
    $("#term"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('name','data[Term]['+lastRow+'][from]').attr('id','from'+lastRow);
    $("#term"+lastRow+" input:eq(1)").attr('name','data[Term]['+lastRow+'][to]').attr('id','to'+lastRow);
    $("#term"+lastRow+" input:eq(2)").attr('name','data[Term]['+lastRow+'][register_end]').attr('id','end_register'+lastRow);
    $("#term"+lastRow+" select").attr('name','data[Term]['+lastRow+'][location_id]').attr('id','termLocationId'+lastRow);
}

function removeTerm(x) {
    $("#term"+x).remove();
}
```

```
<script>
$("#from0, #from1, #from2, #from3, #from4").datetimepicker();
</script>

<script>
$('#to0, #to1, #to2, #to3, #to4').datetimepicker();
</script>

<script>
$('#end_register0, #end_register1, #end_register2, #end_register3, #end_register4').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

Could anybody help me please? I don't know why datetimepicker is not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any widget named `datetimepicker` on jquery-ui?
Well, This code just add `datepicker` if you are using jquery-ui... If you are using other plugin, then modify..

```
function addTerm() {
    lastRow++;
    $("#mytable tbody>tr:#term0").clone(true).attr('id','term'+lastRow).removeAttr('style').insertBefore("#mytable tbody>tr:#trAdd");
    $("#term"+lastRow+" button").attr('onclick','removeTerm('+lastRow+')');
    $("#term"+lastRow+" input:first").attr('name','data[Term]['+lastRow+'][from]').attr('id','from'+lastRow);
    $("#term"+lastRow+" input:eq(1)").attr('name','data[Term]['+lastRow+'][to]').attr('id','to'+lastRow);
    $("#term"+lastRow+" input:eq(2)").attr('name','data[Term]['+lastRow+'][register_end]').attr('id','end_register'+lastRow);
    $("#term"+lastRow+" select").attr('name','data[Term]['+lastRow+'][location_id]').attr('id','termLocationId'+lastRow);
    $('#from'+lastRow).datepicker(); // added
    $('#to'+lastRow).datepicker(); //added
    $('#end_register'+lastRow).datepicker(); //added
}
```

Comment: I'm using jQuery-Timepicker-Addon: https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

Comment: just call `datetimepicker` instead of `datepicker`